# Object.assign, values only

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two objects.  One is a source object, and another is a deep copy of the source object.  The same keys exist in each, but the deep copy may have different values than the source object.  For instance:

```
{
  id: 123,
  people: [{
      name: "Bob",
      age: 50
   }, {
      name: "Alice",
      age: 40
  }]
}

and

{
  id: 123,
  people: [{
      name: "Bob",
      age: 51 // bob is older now
   }, {
      name: "Alice",
      age: 40
  }]
}
```

**Please note that the object is much deeper with many more keys/objects/arrays/values.**

I want to apply **values** (and values only) from the updated copy back on to the source object.

The important piece is that I need to maintain the original reference points of the source object.  This means I cannot do any of the following:

```
sourceObject = updatedCopiedObject;
```

because it overwrites the source object and breaks references to the source object

```
Object.assign(sourceObject, updatedCopiedObject);
```

because, as the docs say:

> Properties in the target object will be overwritten by properties in
>   the sources if they have the same key.  Later sources' properties will
>   similarly overwrite earlier ones.

In other words, it also overwrites the references of the source object.

What I need to do is exactly what Object.assign would do, but NOT overwrite properties - **just change the values where properties match**.

I don't know of any built in method which will do this in the necessary recursive/deep manner.  I can write a method which does, but I wanted to see if there was already a solution to this problem first.

Comment: So your question is, is there a built-in method which does what you want? No, there is not.

Comment: Yes - thank you.  All I wanted to know.

Comment: @torazaburo Have you considered posting your comment at an Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know of any built in method which will do this in the necessary recursive/deep manner. I can write a method which does, but I wanted to see if there was already a solution to this problem first.

No, there is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries()` to iterate properties and values of an object as key, value pairs of an array. If the value is an object call the same function recursively to reassign the property value, else set the value to the source object property value

```js
let source = {
  id: 123,
  people: [{
      name: "Bob",
      age: 50
   }, {
      name: "Alice",
      age: 40
  }]
}



let copy = {
  id: 123,
  people: [{
      name: "Bob",
      age: 51 // bob is older now
   }, {
      name: "Alice",
      age: 40
  }]
}

const reassign = (s, c) => {
  for (let [key, prop] of Object.entries(c)) {
    if (typeof prop !== "object") {
      s[key] = prop;
    } else {
      reassign(s[key], prop)
    }
  }
  return [s, c]
}

console.log(reassign(source, copy));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Something like this is my last resort as the real object is huge and complicated.  Was hoping for a built in method similar to Object.assign.

Comment: @oooyaya `Object.entries()` is a built in method. You could possibly alternatively utilize `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` `replacer` functions. You will still need to recursively iterate all property values which are objects.

Comment: Yeah but it's used in a recursive method.  So is Object.keys or for...in, but using either just helps iterate through the object to copy it manually.  It doesnt really do much to solve the problem.

Comment: _"Yeah but it's used in a recursive method."_ Yes, that is a requirement of the Question, given that expected result is iterating all properties and values of a JavaScript object; save for converting the JavaScript object to a string using `JSON.stringify()` and `String.prototype.replace()` to change values. _"So is Object.keys or for...in, but using either just helps iterate through the object to copy it manually. It doesnt really do much to solve the problem."_ Yes, the expected result described at original Question is returned from the function. What "problem" are you attempting to resolve?

Comment: "I don't know of any built in method which will do this in the necessary recursive/deep manner. **I can write a method which does, but I wanted to see if there was already a solution to this problem first.**"

Comment: What do you mean by "built in method"? Each of `Object.entries()`, `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` are "built-in" methods, unless you are using a different definition of "built-in" than am considering here?

Comment: `Object.assign()` is just a recursive copying of one object over another.  Its one method, whose functionality is abstracted away so that it is usable as one line.  It's built-in to the language.  No need to write your own method to do it.  I'm looking for exactly the same functionality, except limited only to values.  The answer, as far as I can tell, is "this does not exist in the language".  I can write the method to do so, but didn't want to re-write a method built in to the language that I wasn't aware of.  I don't want to rewrite Object.assignValuesOnly if it already exists.

Comment: `Object.assign()` is not recursive. Have you read the specification of each of `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`, each of which recursively iterate all properties and values of a `JSON` string or JavaScript object?

Comment: Yes.  I'm using parse/stringify to make the copy in the first place.  I'm relying on the by-reference nature of objects to handle data binding for me.  That's why assign won't work - it breaks the reference.

Comment: Then it is necessary to compose a recursive or other solution to iterate the JavaScript object.

Comment: Yes - that's what I was wondering.  I don't know what I don't know so was asking if there was already a method which does this before I make one.  The answer is "no, there isn't."  Thank you for the help sir/maam.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for assigning the value.

This proposal iterates the source object and create new target properties if necessary and assign the value if no nested object is found.

```js
function update(target, source) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) {
        if (source[key] && typeof source[key] === 'object') {
            return update(target[key] = target[key] || Array.isArray(source[key]) ? [] : {}, source[key]);
        }
        if (target[key] !== source[key]) {
            target[key] = source[key];
        }
    });
}

var obj1 = { id: 123, people: [{ name: "Bob", age: 50 }, { name: "Alice", age: 40 }] }, obj2 = { id: 123, people: [{ name: "Bob", age: 51 }, { name: "Alice", age: 40 }] };

update(obj1, obj2);
console.log(obj1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

guest271314's answer helped me write a recursive solution for assigning "values only" from one object to another.  For my application, I needed to change it a bit to handle arrays within the objects:

```
assignObject (target = {}, source) {
  let value = null
  let keys = Object.keys(source)
  for (let key of keys) {
    value = source[key]
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Array]') {
        target[key] = value
      } else {
        assignObject(target[key], value)
      }
    } else {
      target[key] = value
    }
  }
  return target
}
```